# Is there a way to have different justify-content values for different rows inside a flexbox-container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

Is there a way to have different justify-content values for different rows inside a flexbox-container?
Here is my html:

```html
    <div class="wrapper flex-container">
      <div class="flex-item">
        <h2>Text</h2>
        <p>Text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-item">
        <h2>Text</h2>
        <p>Text</p>
      </div>
      <figure class="flex-item"><img src="materiale/junckers.png" alt="junckers"></figure>
      <figure class="flex-item"><img src="materiale/byg-garanti.png" alt="byg-garanti"></figure>
      <figure class="flex-item"><img src="materiale/gulvbranchen.png" alt="gulvbranchen"></figure>
    </div>
```

I want the first two flex-items (the two div's) to fill one row and to be aligned in accordance with justify-content: space-between;
And I want the three last flex-items (the three figure's) to fill the next row and to be aligned in accordance with justify-content: space-evenly;

Is that possible in the same flex-container?

Comment: Perhaps a drawing would be helpful.

Comment: For first item use `margin-right: auto;`. last 3 item use `margin-left: auto;` and  `margin-right: auto;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **no**.

In `grid`, there is the `justify-self` property in which this would be true. However, in `flex` there is no support for this style as of *May 2022.*

`flex` does support `align-self` for aligning flex item's on the y-axis (`align-items`), but not for the x-axis (`justify-content`).

**The good news.**

You can still replicate these styles in your stylesheet but they will have to be done manually. You can target the first and second `flex-item` and use `width: calc(100%/2)` for the first two flex items that you want to each take 50%. Then you can add `flex-wrap: wrap` on to your `flex-container` so the image `flex-items` wrap onto a new row. Then you can replicate `justify-content: space-between;` by adding `margin: auto;` to those respective flex-items.

See below:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item:first-child,
.flex-item:nth-child(2) {
  width: calc(100%/2);
  outline: dotted 1px black;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(3),
.flex-item:nth-child(4),
.flex-item:nth-child(5) {
  outline: solid 1px;
  background: orange;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <h2>Text</h2>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <h2>Text</h2>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <figure class="flex-item" style="margin-right: auto;"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100/000/fff" alt="junckers"></figure>
  <figure class="flex-item" style="margin: auto;"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100/000/fff" alt="byg-garanti"></figure>
  <figure class="flex-item" style="margin-left: auto;"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100/000/fff" alt="gulvbranchen"></figure>
</div>
```